# How to submit kafka offset after processing batch records

Tags: java, performance, spring-kafka

I'm using `spring-kafka` and consuming batch records from kafka topic and submitting offset by `AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.BATCH`.

In my case processing batch records is taking time (approximately 20 seconds), and consumer thread waits until batch process is completed and then do the poll again(submits offset at this poll). In this case i will assign `List` of records to a thread (name: `ProcessThread`) that will process all the records and give result back to consumer thread, and then consumer thread will log the result. (in all this process consumer thread will wait until it gets the results from the `ProcessThread`, which causing low performance.

Is there any way that `ProcessThread` will take care of submitting offset to kafka? so that consumer thread will not need to wait, and for every poll it will create a new `processThread`

In my case i have topic with 20 partitions and 10 pods, each pod with 2 consumer threads (spring kafka concurrent consumers), each poll 100 records (processing all these records by using spring boot threading `@Async`)

By above configuration i can process 1 million records in 2 hours and i need to drag it down to at least 40 minutes.

Any help is Appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You should upgrade to at least 1.3.7. The current version is 2.1.10. There is no separate thread in those. Only the consumer thread can send the offsets . The consumer is not thread safe.

You should not hand off to a separate thread. Use higher concurrency and more partitions.

Comment: do you mean i should upgrade spring kafka to 1.3.7, the how does it has effect on performance? can you please provide some docs to it

Comment: Yes but the current is 2.1.10.

Comment: you mean get more partition topic and assign each consumer to each partition, am i right? what exactly this means `There is no separate thread in those.`?

Comment: i have one more doubt, do kafka rebalance if consumer is not responded for long time like 25 or 30 seconds ?

Comment: In versions before 1.3.0 we had 2 threads per consumer. A consumer thread and a listener thread. This was needed to avoid a rebalance due to a slow listener. KiP-62 fixed that. Now  max.poll.interval is used for rebalance . It is 5 minutes by default.

Comment: regarding this statement `The consumer is not thread safe.`, if i run my application with concurrency of 2 (which means two consumer threads call parallely my `@KafkaListener` method, if my code handles concurrency then that should be fine right? or do i need to take more precaution? @Gray Russell

Comment: No; it's taken care of for you. However, if you use some of the newer APIs that give you direct access to the consumer, you must only call its methods on the listener thread (which is the consumer thread).

Comment: This is great, i'm using 1.3.7 and i guess this is perfect version for it.