# Update Kafka commit offset after successful batch insert

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a spring-kafka consumer which reads records and hands them over to a cache. A scheduled task will clear the records in the cache periodically. I want to update the COMMIT OFFSET only after a batch has been successfully saved in the database. I tried passing the acknowledgment object to the cache service to invoke the acknowledge method as shown below.

```
public class KafkaConsumer {
    @KafkaListener( topicPattern = "${kafka.topicpattern}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory" )
    public void receive( ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment ) {
        cacheService.add( record.value(), acknowledgment );
    }
}

public class CacheService {
    // concurrency handling has been left out in favor of readability
    public void add( String record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment ) {
        this.records.add(record);
        this.lastAcknowledgment = acknowledgment;
    }

    public void saveBatch() { //called by scheduled task
        if( records.size() == BATCH_SIZE ) {
            // perform batch insert into database
            this.lastAcknowledgment.acknowledge();
            this.records.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

The AckMode has been set as follows:

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode( AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL );
```

And the Auto Commit is false:

```
config.put( ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false );
```

Even though the acknowledge method is called, the commit offset is not updated. What is the best way to update the commit offset after persisting the records?

I'm using spring-kafka 2.1.7.RELEASE.

---

**EDIT**: After @GaryRussell [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54383839/update-kafka-commit-offset-after-successful-batch-insert#comment95581200_54383961) that acknowledgements made by foreign threads are performed by the consumer thread during the next poll, I rechecked my code and found a bug in how the last acknowledgement object is set. **After fixing this, the commit offset IS UPDATED as expected**. So this issue has been resolved. However, I have no way to mark this question as answered.

Comment: is `scheduled task` a different thread? i believe this `lastAcknowledgment.acknowledge();` should be called on consumer thread, and how are you defining offset is not submited?

Comment: and what is your spring-kafka version?

Comment: Yes, the scheduled task is a different thread because I don't want to block the consumption of messages, while they are being persisted. Using the command line tool kafka-consumer-groups.sh I can see that the current-offset is not updated.

Comment: Its spring-kafka 2.1.7.RELEASE

Comment: you need to hold the consumer thread

Answer (score 3):

Here is the problem, Consumer thread is responsible to commit the offset. At the time of poll consumer thread will submit the previous batch offset.

Since in your case `AUTO_COMMIT` is false and `lastAcknowledgment.acknowledge()` is not acknowledge the offset is not submit.

Only one way to do this, As soon as you get the poll records make `Schedule` task as `Async` and hold the consumer thread and submit the offset after completion of Async task, Check this answer for reference [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52617111/how-to-submit-kafka-offset-after-processing-batch-records)

**Note** If you hold consumer thread more than 5 minutes rebalance will takes place [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_1010_notable)

> he new Java Consumer now supports heartbeating from a background thread. There is a new configuration max.poll.interval.ms which controls the maximum time between poll invocations before the consumer will proactively leave the group **(5 minutes by default)**. The value of the configuration request.timeout.ms must always be larger than `max.poll.interval.ms` because this is the maximum time that a JoinGroup request can block on the server while the consumer is rebalancing, so we have changed its default value to just above 5 minutes. Finally, the default value of `session.timeout.ms` has been adjusted down to 10 seconds, and the default value of `max.poll.records` has been changed to 500.

**Special Note** from spring kafka >2.1.5

Acknowledgments made on foreign threads will be performed by the consumer thread just before the next poll Thanks for @Gary Russell for this information

Comment: Acknowledgments made on "foreign" threads will be performed by the consumer thread just before the next poll(); see [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/6d3eb9aa88e5ee7b0ebd9be26d20c58808eb5fcf).

Comment: but here i believe `Ack` is not happening before the next `poll`, as soon as consumer thread is free it will poll the next offset right? @GaryRussell and this commit is from `2.1.5`?

Comment: That is correct; the time the async offset commit actually occurs depends on the state of the consumer thread when the ack is submitted. If it is "stuck" in a `poll()` (and no more records are available), the commit will occur when the poll exits (times out) and just before the next poll, If the poll returns some more records, the commit won't occur until those records have all been sent to the listener. `processCommits()` is called just before `poll()` and commits any pending offsets (all offsets committed from async threads are added to the pending queue). Yes, it was added in 2.1.5.

Comment: We have no choice - the Consumer is not thread-safe. For the listener to have complete control, the ack **must be performed on the consumer thread** (and then with MANUAL_IMMEDIATE so the commit occurs immediately).

Comment: @GaryRussell - Thank you so much for confirming that the acknowledgement made by foreign threads is still performed by the consumer thread. After this, I checked my code and found a bug in how the last acknowledgement is set. After fixing this, the commit offset is updated as you have mentioned.